# Return Single Value Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build a custom zip code search to find a delivery fee, but I can't seem to get it right.

First up this is how I have my form set up on the front-end:

```
<form class="delivery-fee" role="search" method="get" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Find Your Delivery Area:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" value="" name="zipcode" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" pattern="\d*" />
        <input type="submit" value="See Delivery Minimum" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I've got my data set up like this:

```
$delivery_areas = [
    'Rancho Cucamonga' => [
        'zipcodes' => [91701, 91729, 91730, 91737, 91739],
        'fee'      => 100
    ],
    'Upland' => [
        'zipcodes' => [91784, 91785, 91786],
        'fee'      => 150
    ]
];
```

This is how I'm looping through my data:

```
foreach ($delivery_areas as $key => $delivery_area) {
    if (is_array($delivery_area)) {
        if (in_array($_GET['zipcode'], $delivery_area['zipcodes'])) {
            echo $delivery_area['fee'];
        } else {
            echo 'Error message';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is if I do a search for say 91701 I do get the correct fee returned, but I'm also getting the error message with it. On the flip side I'll also get two error messages if nothing is found.

Any suggestions on how I could get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your code by using a var, e.g.:

```
$fee = -1;
foreach ($delivery_areas as $key => $delivery_area) {
    if (is_array($delivery_area)) {
        if (in_array($_GET['zipcode'], $delivery_area['zipcodes'])) {
            $fee = $delivery_area['fee'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($fee == -1)
    echo 'Error message';
else
    echo $fee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```
$fee = 0;
foreach ($delivery_areas as $key => $delivery_area) {
    if (is_array($delivery_area) && in_array($_GET['zipcode'], $delivery_area['zipcodes'])) {
        $fee = $delivery_area['fee']; break;
    }
}

echo $fee!=0 ? $fee : 'Error Message';
```